# Please help restore my crashed launcher/compizconfig

Tags: 11.10, launcher

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I create launchers on my desktop?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/64222/how-can-i-create-launchers-on-my-desktop)

I have just upgraded from 11.04 to 11.10. Everything worked fine at first, but at one point when I was editing some CompizConfig settings (just something basic like 'number of desktops'), CompizConfig crashed.
Then the whole launcher disappeared, along with most of the buttons in the top panel. The shutdown button, calendar, etc. all went, leaving just the tabs from File to Help.

Also, windows now have the title and File, Edit..(etc) tabs on 2 separate lines, instead of the new format where hovering over the bar switches which one is visible.

I have since been using Ctrl+Alt+T to open a terminal and open applications, shut down, etc, from there.

I have typed in the command:
unity --reset
which has some effect, but the terminal never reaches the end of the task.
I've also done apt-get update, which completed fine.

Can anyone help me restore the launcher and panel functions?? I am getting most frustrated by the fact that once I have opened Firefox, I can't enter any other commands!

Answer (score 0):

This works for me.

If you're 'locked out' like you explain, then you can use keyboard shortcuts to gain some control. (This helped me when I lost Unity and GUI components.)

For instance:

Ctrl + Alt + F4  - Will let you gain terminal access.

or

Ctrl + Alt + Delete  - Will log you out.

When you're logged out and at the pretty login screen, choose **Ubuntu 2D**.

When you're logged into Ubuntu 2D, you can go back into CompizConfig and readjust.

What you need to do is disable CUBE and ROTATE, and enable UNITY and DESKTOP WALL.

If you experience crashes after checking or unchecking DESKTOP CUBE, this just checking them in different orders... you'll get it.

You can also go to Preferences >> Reset to Defaults. [This might solve your particular issue.]

I still haven't figured out how to properly get DESKTOP CUBE going with 11.10 .